# How to reduce size of WCF proxy class

Tags: wcf

I consume a WCF service with thousands of methods on it and the generated client side proxy class is about 8mb.
This is causing performance issues when it is instantiated.

We only use around 20 of the methods, is there a safe way to generate a proxy with only these methods and their associated types?

Is there another way around this issue?

My understanding is that the proxy class should be created for each use as they cannot be reused once they have entered a failed state.

Answer (score 0):

(Can't comment sry) Have you tried creating 2 classes one with just the methods you use and leave the big one in case you need it? Although if you didn't say i imagine you might've tried it first :S